# Playing an array of sounds, windows phone 7

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7, audio

My question is the following:

How do I set up an array of sounds, so that a single button can play them? I have 5 wavs (sounds1.wav, sounds2.wav .... sounds5.wav), and ideally I would like for them to be random instead of a set order, but i have absolutely no idea if that is possible.

I am using this code as a basis:

```
var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sounds/sound1.wav");
     var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
     FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
     effect.Play();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store them in an array of streams, but it's only a good idea to do this if your `wav` files aren't big as you may surpass the 90mb memory usage limit if they are.

```
Stream[] myStreamArray = new Stream[5];
myStreamArray[0] = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sounds/sound1.wav");
//etc.. (you could use a for loop if your sounds are named in a pattern)
```

You can then pick a random number, using the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class, from `0` to `4` (inclusive). This will mean that the chosen sound will be random instead of playing in any particular order.
 To play, you can just use your code above but replace the `FromStream` line to something like this:

```
var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(myStreamArray[randomNumber]);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you KeyboardP. The sound wavs are no more than 8kbs, and so this shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for helping me understand these features too. I was looking all over the place for a random number generator in code, and this is perfect.

Comment: Hmm, Stream is not a valid directive or assembly... but I'm using: using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;   any thoughts?

Comment: @topcoverwannabe - That code must be in a method, you can't just put it at the top of the file.

Comment: @topcoderwannabe - `Stream` is part of the `System.IO` namespace, so try adding `using System.IO;` at the top of your class.